# Exercise about localization and monic polynomial

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Please help me solve this exercise,

> Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset. Prove that if every element of $R_{S}$ is a root of a monic polynomial of $R[x]$ then $R= R_{S}$.

It's trivial that $R\subset R_{S}$, but inverse is true when $S=\{1\}$. But I can't prove this!

I know, if $\frac{r}{s} \in R_{S}$ then by hypothesis there exists a polynomial $$f(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_{o}$$ in $R[x]$ such that $f(\frac{r}{s})=0$.

So
$$r^{n}+a_{n-1}r^{n-1}s+\cdots + a_{0}s^{n}=0.$$
But this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac{1}{s}\in R_{S}$. By hypothesis and the above mentioned proof,
$$1=st$$ for some $t\in R$ (note that $R$ is domain).

This means every elements of $S$ belong to $U(R)$.

But by definition, $R_S$ is smallest ring such that every elements of $S$ is a unit. So we showed $R=R_S$.